# Create database account on Azure with specific password using ARM templates

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I want to run Azure Resource Group Deployment as part of my deployment process. This should create two resources: App Service (asp.net core) and DocumentDB account.
After that I need to store account credentials (account name and password) in App Settings block of my App Service. Normally I could configure App Service to read the password from existing Azure Key Vault.
But if the database account is not created yet, the password is generated automatically and I would need to update it manually.

Is it possible to create the database account specifying the password (reading value from Key Vault)? This way the deployment would be automated whether the database account was created or not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where's the problem in this one, just specify the secret in your template:

```
"parameters": {
  "adminPassword": {
    "reference": {
      "keyVault": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/{group-name}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vault-name}"
      }, 
      "secretName": "sqlAdminPassword" 
    } 
  }
}
```

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter/

Comment: If the databaseaccount does not exist, the password is not set yet. This means that I have no value for that in KeyVault

Comment: I don't understand. KeyVault has nothing to do with your database

Comment: That's correct, it's not about reading value from KeyVault in general, but passing it's value while creating database account

Comment: well,i've pasted you the exact code to do that. I don't understand what else do you expect? Take a look at my template that does exactly what you are asking for (but its passing value to another template, which in turn uses that value as dba password)
https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/ARM/parent.json
line 166.